# Merge 'toilet-usage' into 'hygiene'

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The tag [toilet-usage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toilet-usage) is obsolete, and is a synonym to [hygiene](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hygiene). However, the former tag is visible on several questions, such as [Stuck without toilet paper while travelling - what is the best approach?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5801/stuck-without-toilet-paper-while-travelling-what-is-the-best-approach) .

This is confusing. It led me to try to edit a question with [hygiene](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hygiene) ([How can I wash myself Indian-style (using water not toilet paper) in Western toilets?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25470/how-can-i-wash-myself-indian-style-using-water-not-toilet-paper-in-western-toi)) to add the [toilet-usage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toilet-usage) tag to it.

Can we avoid this confusion, by merging [toilet-usage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toilet-usage) into [hygiene](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hygiene)?

Comment: This seems like a possible bug to me. I would expect that when a tag synonym is created, that the tags should also be merged. It might be worth bringing up on Meta.SO (if someone hasn't already).

Comment: @Flimzy It's not a bug, but the intermediate status of unmerged synonyms can be weird sometimes. The solution is for a moderator to merge the tags. This is a separate step because unlike synonymization, merging cannot be undone.

Comment: @Gilles: Makes sense.

Comment: I have updated the question to ask simply for a tag merge.  I hope you don't mind, Andrew, as this seems like the most straight forward action, based on @Gille's information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tags merged as suggested. A possible reason for this omission is that the tag synonym was approved by users with enough rep on posts with this tag.