# Should we flush the [toilet]?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There's currently seven questions tagged [toilets](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toilets), while there's [at least 47 questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bhygiene%5D%20toilet%20is%3Aquestion) in the [hygiene](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hygiene) tag about toilets.

[toilet-usage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toilet-usage) was previously merged into [hygiene](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hygiene), as noted in [Merge 'toilet-usage' into 'hygiene'](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1676/merge-toilet-usage-into-hygiene)

Comment: Either flush or retag relevant hygiene into toilet questions. Why do you favour flushing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, we should flush the toilet.

Comment: Solid life advice -- always flush the toilet.

Comment: And don't forget to brush after you flush.

Comment: OK so this was agreed eight or nine months ago but I see this tag has not only not been merged into "hygiene" but it is actively spreading right now. It's not needed as seen by the tag wiki which only tells us what toilets are as if that's a mystery, instead of telling us how they relate to travel and what kind of questions would fit: "Bathrooms, restrooms, water closets, toilets... facilities to take care of nature's call while traveling.". **Flush please...**